# Only Admin receives email

Tags: wp-admin, user-registration, email, code, notifications

is there a suitable code for blocking all registered users' outgoing email but only the admin receives all emails. I need a send all emails to admin only situation.

Comment: Are you asking for any specific plugin or what please elaborate your issue.

Comment: are you asking how to do it, or for a product/plugin recommendation? Note that just asking for a copy paste solution is considered rude here, an answer is meant to explain how to do it so that people can learn, but dropping a block of code with no context is not considered a good answer. People may think you're asking them to work for free

Answer (score 1):

Mail sent from WP uses `wp_mail()` function. There is a filter that you can use before the mail is sent to filter the arguments used in the `wp_mail()` function, including the $to value.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail/

Look at the example code on that page to get an idea of how to block (or redirect) all mail sent by `wp_mail()`. You could put your implementation of that in your Child Theme's functions file, or your own private plugin.

It is possible that a plugin or a theme might not use the `wp_mail()` function, using instead `mail()` or their own implementation of phpMailer (which `wp_mail()` uses).